# Caching issue on Drupal 8 custom block module displaying IP Address

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I've created a simple custom block module that displays the IP Address of the user visiting a website. When the site gets a visitor, that visitor sees their own IP Address displayed in the block. I don't need to store this information or use it for any other purpose, this is only for aesthetic purposes, thus only the block plugin is necessary. The module works fine and displays the IP, however, it's cached and the IP doesn't update unless I manually visit the performance page and clear the site cache. How do I override this so the visitor sees their current IP Address?

Here's my custom block module file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tester\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class newid extends BlockBase {

/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $request = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
    return array('#markup' => $request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a cache context to your render array. There is an [IP Cache Context](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21Context%21IpCacheContext.php). The ID to use is just `ip`.

Try this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\tester\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class newid extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $request = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
    return [
      '#markup' => $request,
      '#cache' => [
        'contexts' => [
          'ip',
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }
  
}
```